# Selenium WebDriver (2.25) Timeout Not Working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I think I've read all the Selenium timeout questions on Stack Overflow, yet neither implicit nor explicit timeout works in my Selenium webdriver 2.25 (Python 2.7 binding) and both "no_timeout_here =" lines would hang forever --

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(6)               
browser.set_page_load_timeout(30)        
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
try:
    #no_timeout_here = browser.find_element_by_id("id_not_found")
    no_timeout_here = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(lambda browser:
            browser.find_element_by_id("id_not_found"))
except:
    raise
```

All pointers will be greatly appreciated!

**Update Oct. 16th**

Thanks to seleniumnewbie for your comprehensive answer, however, your unittest code still hangs on my Ubuntu 11.04 (64-bit) under Python 2.7 --

```
(2012/10/17 11:51:58)$ time ./timeout.py 
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
...
KeyboardInterrupt

real    2m26.572s
user    0m0.368s
sys 0m0.232s

(2012/10/17 11:54:26)$ python -V
Python 2.7.2+

(2012/10/17 11:57:04)$ uname -a
Linux 3.0.0-26-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 25 17:19:22 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

(2012/10/17 11:57:10)$ ls selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar
```

May I know your OS/Python version?

Comment: What is happening? what are you expecting? what help do you need ?

Comment: "What is happening?" -- "Both no_timeout_here lines hang forever"; "what are you expecting?" -- "no_timeout_here line raises exception after a reasonable, preferably configurable, amount of time"; "what help do you need?" -- "A way to achieve the timeout".

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but your first "no_timeout_here" works fine for me with OS X, python 2.7.3, and selenium 2.25.0

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Firefox 17 and Selenium 2.26.0 then you are hitting defect #4814: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4814

Comment: If you are a Travis-CI user like me then you can execute the following shell script before launching your tests:
# Remove after 4814 is resolved
# http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4814
wget http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/16.0/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-16.0.tar.bz2
tar -xjf firefox-16.0.tar.bz2
export PATH=./firefox:$PATH


This should also work for local testing.

Answer (score 4):

Based on answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692172/test-dynamically-loaded-content-with-selenium-web-driver)

### 1

I would  recommend using WebDriverWait with ExpectedConditons.

```
//scroll down with Javascript first
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("selector")));
//interact with your element
element.click()
```

Take a look at the guidance provided by Selenium Official page:
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

### 2

try using fluent wait in particular. The main feature is:

*An implementation of the Wait interface that may have its timeout and polling interval configured on the fly.
Each FluentWait instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the condition. Furthermore, the user may configure the wait to ignore specific types of exceptions whilst waiting, such as NoSuchElementExceptions when searching for an element on the page.*

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                }
                }
);
                           return  foo;              }     ;
```

The method described returns you web element you can operate with.
So the approach be the following:
1) you need to find the selectors  of elements you expect to be rendered after scrolling
e.g.

```
String cssSelector = "blablabla"
```

2) scroll down with js
3)

```
WebElement neededElement  = fluentWait(cssSelector);
neededElement.click();
//neededElement.getText().trim();
```

you can get more info about fluent wait [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)

**UPDATE**

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest, time, re

class Sdsdsd(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []

    def test_sdsdsd(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get ("http://www.google.com")
        try:
             driver.find_element_by_id("id_not_found")# I am only searching for the element not assigning it to anything.
        except:
            raise


    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

and I get this exception, which is desired

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_sdsdsd (__main__.Sdsdsd)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sdsdsd.py", line 19, in test_sdsdsd
    driver.find_element_by_id("id_not_found")
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 172, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 525, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 144, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 110, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id_not_found"}' ; Stacktrace: Method WebDriverError threw an error in file:///private/var/folders/TA/TAS7MYfcEuG3lBNHwhrjRU+++TI/-Tmp-/tmpEf_lrD/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/resource/modules/utils.js 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 33.818s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Also note that it failed after 33 seconds, which means it waited for 30 seconds before erroring out.

When i change the implicit wait to `self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)`

I get this error

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_sdsdsd (__main__.Sdsdsd)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sdsdsd.py", line 19, in test_sdsdsd
    driver.find_element_by_id("id_not_found")
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 172, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 525, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 144, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.2.0-py2.6.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 110, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id_not_found"}' ; Stacktrace: Method WebDriverError threw an error in file:///private/var/folders/TA/TAS7MYfcEuG3lBNHwhrjRU+++TI/-Tmp-/tmpXSbCY0/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/resource/modules/utils.js 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 18.843s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: 1 is just the Java binding of my (failed) Python sample

Comment: Thanks, but I'm yet to be convinced that I have to rewrite my entire Python program into Java.

Comment: instead of 2nd part of your post you could simply share this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692172/test-dynamically-loaded-content-with-selenium-web-driver
;-)

Comment: @Jerry, I manage to get the error message, check out my update.

Comment: @seleniumnewbie, thanks, but your test code still hangs on my machine. I've updated my question with the details.