# python selenium hangs on finding nonexistent elements

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I'm using selenium with Python and it always freezes when I search for an element that does not exist. I've really tried everything (Firefox version 17.0.1):

```
>>> import selenium
>>> selenium.__version__
'2.26.0'
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
>>> ff = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> ff.implicitly_wait(5)
>>> ff.set_page_load_timeout(5)
>>> ff.set_script_timeout(5)
>>> waiter = WebDriverWait(ff, 5)
>>> waiter.until(lambda ff: ff.find_element_by_name("foo"))
```

That last command freezes indefinitely. How do I get firefox to simply return None or throw an exception when it doesn't find an element, instead of hanging **forever**? I'm using selenium 2.26.0

Comment: what happens if you lose the `implicitly_wait(5)`?

Comment: @root: the same, it still freezes. I only tried the implicitly_wait because it was freezing in the first place. It also freezes without using the `waiter`

Comment: When I do exactly this, it works fine, and I get a timeout exception.  What is freezing here?  Starting up Firefox?  The waiter?

Comment: @sr2222: the `ff.find_element_by_name("foo")` freezes, whether I use a waiter or not. What version of firefox/selenium are you using?

Comment: Version issue between Firefox and selenium.  Almost every release of Firefox over the last year or so has broken selenium element lookup or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in version 2.26.0, `pip install selenium==2.27.0` fixed it on my computer.

Comment: most beautiful NoSuchElementException ever:)

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880024/selenium-webdriver-2-25-timeout-not-working/)

If you are using Firefox 17 and Selenium 2.26.0 then you are hitting defect #4814: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4814

Comment: that seems to refer to `click`, though - I'm not even clicking

Comment: No its about finding an element. You need to up your version to 2.27

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm using this work-around:

```
def selenium_safe_find_element_by_name(ff, element_name):
    elements = ff.find_elements_by_name(element_name)
    if not elements:
        raise ValueError("<name=%s> not found" % (element_name,))

    return elements[0]
```

But it really seems that this should somehow work without that workaround.