# Sellenium randomly freezes after few succesfull iterations in the loop

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

When I run the loop first few iterations (sometimes 5 , sometimes 15. It seems random) work just fine , but the program for some reasons hangs indefinetly at some point

```
for url in links: 
    driver.get(url)
    print(url)
    li_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-sfcl1s")
    price_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-t9ee1.er34gjf0")
    #some job on python lists
```

The sites are similar and look like [this](https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/2-pok-apartament-55m2-zoliborz-arkadia-garaz-taras-ul-rydygiera-CID3-IDVYvD9.html)

What I tried:

First I felt inspired by this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996815/python-3-selenium-webdriverwait-causes-script-to-hang-freeze-forever?fbclid=IwAR3qbcV8bu6RmVt0g6g0RpaYRVbBZx3rhSRJiaIJvlw4Kmtz7J1kK8aRlT8) to use `driver.command_executor.set_timeout(10)` but it does not solve the issue.

I tried structures ,,try & except'' like this:

```
for url in links: 
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        print(url)
        li_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-sfcl1s")
        price_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-t9ee1.er34gjf0")
        #some job on python lists
    except: 
        print("error has occured")
        driver.get(url)
        print(url)
        li_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-sfcl1s")
        price_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-t9ee1.er34gjf0")
        #some job on python lists
```

It does execute the print function in except block , yet it stops at `driver.get(url)` and spits errors regarding the sellenium like:

```
ReadTimeoutError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16228\257283962.py in <module>
     19     except:
     20         print("error has occured")
---> 21         driver.get(url)
     22         print(url)
     23         li_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-sfcl1s")

C:\Users\Public\anacondaa\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    351     def get(self, url: str) -> None:
    352         """Loads a web page in the current browser session."""
--> 353         self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
    354 
    355     @property
```

Restarting webdriver seemed to work , but it still stops after few iterations. Since I have around 900 sites to scrap it's not realy a viable option.

I have thought to replace standard `li_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-sfcl1s")` with something like: `li_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "css-sfcl1s")))` yet the problem persists. First few iterations work fine , and then it stops.

Any ideas how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is causing your problem, but if I had to guess I'd say it's either bad URLs or chromdriver isn't closing once it's finished. Try killing the existing instances and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might missunderstand how "try-except" works.
Once exception is caught you are trying to repeat steps that caused the error.
In most cases it won't work.

**What you do is:**

- trying to execute some code
- catching an exception
- re-trying to process "broken" url
- failing because second attempt finish with unhandled exception (thread is interrupted so it's your loop)

**What you should / might do:**

- try to execute some code
- catch an exception
- print message that points url that causes problems (in addition print exception message)
- **do not** try to process "broken" url again

---

Insted of

```
    print("error has occured")
    driver.get(url)
    print(url)
    li_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-sfcl1s")
    price_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-t9ee1.er34gjf0")
    #some job on python lists
```

you should just leave sth like:

```
print("error has occured while processing url: ",url)
```

you could also print exception message to understand what caused error.