# How to test dynamic generated elements in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

For example if u go to Tags page on stack you can start typing tag and when you type more letters the result of search is change. I want to get all elements of my search, e.g. when I type all tags letters. It is possibile with Selenium? Or i need to use JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test dynamically loaded content with Selenium Web Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692172/test-dynamically-loaded-content-with-selenium-web-driver)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Selenium. As you type or make other user actions, the HTML is changing and you can capture an element when it appears. In this case it's recommended to use 'FluentWait' when searching or interacting with an element.